# Custom error page in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I want to show a custom error page on Joomla for error messages like

```
Could not connect to database server
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find joomla error page's template in /templates/system/error.php
You can copy this file to your template's root folder and edit it.